# Spring Boot aspectJ LTW can't weave methods with spring-instrument javaagent

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aop, aspectj

I have spring boot app with this configuration:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement(mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ)
@EnableLoadTimeWeaving
@EnableScheduling
@EnableConfigurationProperties({TelegramBotProperties.class, FreekassaProperties.class})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.birthright.telegrambot.repositories.postgres"}, enableDefaultTransactions = false)
public class Main {
    @Bean
    public ServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() {
        TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
        tomcat.setProtocol("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Nio2Protocol");
        return tomcat;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class);
    }
}
```

and aop.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<aspectj>
    <weaver options="-verbose -showWeaveInfo">
    </weaver>
</aspectj>
```

When i started my application with javaagent spring-instrument i see this info in logs:

```
[AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] info using configuration /home/birthright/telegrambot/target/classes/META-INF/aop.xml
[AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] info using configuration file:/home/birthright/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aspects/5.0.4.RELEASE/spring-aspects-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/META-INF/aop.xml
[AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] info register aspect org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj.AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect
[AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] info register aspect org.springframework.scheduling.aspectj.AnnotationAsyncExecutionAspect
[AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] info register aspect org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AnnotationTransactionAspect
[AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] info register aspect org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.JtaAnnotationTransactionAspect
[AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] info register aspect org.springframework.cache.aspectj.AnnotationCacheAspect
[AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] info register aspect org.springframework.cache.aspectj.JCacheCacheAspect
```

and weaveinfo:

```
[AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] weaveinfo Join point 'method-execution(void org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.setRepositoryMethodMetadata(org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadata))' in Type 'org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository' (SimpleJpaRepository.java:119) advised by around advice from 'org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AnnotationTransactionAspect' (AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:66)
[AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] weaveinfo Join point 'method-execution(void org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.deleteById(java.lang.Object))' in Type 'org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository' (SimpleJpaRepository.java:148) advised by around advice from 'org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AnnotationTransactionAspect' (AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:66)
...
```

So i see only **SimpleJpaRepository** has been weawed, but my **@Transactional** methods in com.birthright.telegrambot.services.* package is not.
I changed my aop.xml config to this:

```
 <weaver options="-verbose -showWeaveInfo">
        <include within="com.birthright.telegrambot.*"/>
    </weaver>
```

but now even SimpleJpaRepository was not weawed.

After i tried to specify the javaagent aspectjweaver-1.8.13 and disable spring annotation **@EnableLoadTimeWeaving**(Otherwise, the application does not start). 
This time all the methods in my packages were woven, but at the start of the application I see the following messages:

```
[AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] info AspectJ Weaver Version 1.8.13 built on Wednesday Nov 15, 2017 at 19:26:44 GMT
[AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] info register classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2
```

and then app started:

```
[MethodUtil@11d73f8] info AspectJ Weaver Version 1.8.13 built on Wednesday Nov 15, 2017 at 19:26:44 GMT
[MethodUtil@11d73f8] info register classloader sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil@11d73f8
```

Is it worth worrying about this? And why with aspectjweaver agent all works fine, but with spring-instrument and **@EnableLoadTimeWeaving** not?

Another embarrassing moment. In the classpath located aop.xml of spring-aspects jar and all aspects are registreed, for example **AnnotationTransactionAspect**. If i change mode to AdviceMode.PROXY does this mean that Spring will create a proxy + aspectJ to screw its aspect to the Transactional method? What to do in this case, exclude aspects in own aop.xml?

Comment: Could you please share an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub incl. Maven build? Then maybe someone can reproduce your problem and help you. You did not even mention whether the application runs in a container (which one?) or stand-alone.

Comment: Hi! I'm having the same difficulties. Have you been able to solve in the meantime?